# CloudPage getting error

Tags: ampscript

I have a CloudPage working with a Double Opt In process. The URL link that opens the CloudPage is as so:

https://pub.s7.exacttarget.com/xxxxxxxx?sk=%%SubId%%&ln=%%Language%%

```
    %%[
VAR @sfid, @lan, @text
SET @sfid = REQUESTPARAMETER("sk")
SET @lan = REQUESTPARAMETER("ln")
]%%

%%[
var @result
set @result = UpdateSingleSalesforceObject("MAG_Subscription__c", @sfid, "MAG_Status__c", "Verified")
]%%

<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title></title>
 <meta name="description" content="">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>
  <p>
    %%[IF @lan == "French"]%%
    Merci d'avoir rejoint McArthurGlen. Nous vous tiendrons au courant de toutes nos offres.
    %%[ELSEIF @lan == "German"]%%
    Danke, dass Sie zu McArthurGlen gekommen sind. Wir werden Sie mit all unseren Angeboten auf dem Laufenden halten.
    %%[ELSEIF @lan == "Italian"]%%
    Grazie per esserti unito a McArthurGlen. Ti aggiorneremo con tutte le nostre offerte.
    %%[ELSEIF @lan == "Greek"]%%
    Ευχαριστώ για τη συμμετοχή σας στο McArthurGlen. Θα σας ενημερώσουμε με όλες τις προσφορές μας.
    %%[ELSEIF @lan == "Dutch"]%%
    Bedankt dat je lid bent geworden van McArthurGlen. We zullen u updaten met al onze aanbiedingen.
    %%[ELSE]%%
    Thanks for joining McArthurGlen. We will update you with all our offers.
    %%[ENDIF]%%
  </p>
</body>
</html>
```

When I remove the dynamic language part between the paragraph tags it works and I tried OutputLine(@lan) but nothing prints. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

forgot the THEN part of the IF statement

```
%%[IF @lan == "French" THEN]%%
    Merci d'avoir rejoint McArthurGlen. Nous vous tiendrons au courant de toutes nos offres.
    %%[ELSEIF @lan == "German" THEN]%%
    Danke, dass Sie zu McArthurGlen gekommen sind. Wir werden Sie mit all unseren Angeboten auf dem Laufenden halten.
    %%[ELSEIF @lan == "Italian" THEN]%%
    Grazie per esserti unito a McArthurGlen. Ti aggiorneremo con tutte le nostre offerte.
    %%[ELSEIF @lan == "Greek" THEN]%%
    Ευχαριστώ για τη συμμετοχή σας στο McArthurGlen. Θα σας ενημερώσουμε με όλες τις προσφορές μας.
    %%[ELSEIF @lan == "Dutch" THEN]%%
    Bedankt dat je lid bent geworden van McArthurGlen. We zullen u updaten met al onze aanbiedingen.
    %%[ELSE]%%
    Thanks for joining McArthurGlen. We will update you with all our offers.
    %%[ENDIF]%%
```